# Testing for value in set of tuples

Tags: python

Suppose we have the following set, `S`, and the value `v`:

```
S = {(0,1),(2,3),(4,5)}
v = 3
```

I want to test if `v` is the second element of any of the pairs within the set. My current approach is:

```
for _, y in S:
    if y == v:
        return True
return False
```

I don't really like this, as I have to put it in a separate function and something is telling me there's probably a nicer way to do it. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 6):

The `any` function is tailor-made for this:

```
any( y == v for (_, y) in S )
```

If you have a large set that doesn't change often, you might want to project the y values onto a set.

```
yy = set( y for (_, y) in S )
v in yy
```

Of course, this is only of benefit if you compute `yy` once after `S` changes, not before every membership test.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do an O(1) lookup, so you don't get much benefit from having a set. You might consider building a second set, especially if you'll be doing lots of lookups.

```
S = {(0,1), (2,3), (4,5)}
T = {x[1] for x in S}

v = 3
if v in T:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Trivial answer is [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) (see Marcelo's answer).

Alternative is [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> zip(*S)
[(4, 0, 2), (5, 1, 3)]
>>> v in zip(*S)[1]
True
```